# How do I find all combinations for an unknown number of options for a product?

Tags: sql, sql-server, combinations

I have a table with 3 columns, Model_Name, Style_Name, and Option_Name.  How do I concatenate all available combinations of the Option_Names grouped by Model_Name and Style_Name?  What I'm trying to do is list a product with every possible combination of options in separate rows.

I have been trying to use `STRING_AGG(Option_Name, ' / ')` WITHIN GROUP, but this just combines all Option_Names.

The table will look like this.

```
Model_Name  | Style_Name | Option_Name 
7000 Series | Front Door | White
7000 Series | Front Door | Extra Lock 
7000 Series | Front Door | Foam Filler
```

Ideally, we would return all of the combinations using SQL Server.

```
7000 Series | Front Door | White
7000 Series | Front Door | White / Extra Lock
7000 Series | Front Door | White / Foam Filler
7000 Series | Front Door | White / Extra Lock / Foam Filler
7000 Series | Front Door | Extra Lock
7000 Series | Front Door | Extra Lock / Foam Filler
7000 Series | Front Door | Foam Filler
```

etc.

```
SELECT Model_Name, Style_Name
  , STRING_AGG(CAST(Option_Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)), ' / ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Model_Name, Style_Name) Option_Name 
FROM [dbo].[Product_Option_Master]
GROUP BY Model_Name, Style_Name
ORDER BY Model_Name, Style_Name
```

This just returns

```
7000 Series | Front Door | White / Extra Lock / Foam Filler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select model_name, style_name, option_name, convert(varchar(max), option_name) as option_names
      from Product_Option_Master pom
      union all
      select cte.model_name, cte.style_name, pom.option_name,
             convert(varchar(max), concat(cte.option_names, ' / ', pom.option_name))
      from cte join
           Product_Option_Master pom
           on pom.model_name = cte.model_name and
              pom.style_name = cte.style_name and
              pom.option_name > cte.option_name
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ba7f65ca2acba7e4aa1726becc187d09) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Gordon, I'm getting the last options repeated over and over.  For instance, I'm getting records where the last option is Screen: Half Screen / Other Options, then I see records where it says Screen: Half Screen / Screen: Half Screen / Screen: Half Screen / Screen: Half Screen / Screen: Half Screen / Option1 / Option2 so on and so forth.  I'm wondering if I need to tweak the join so as to eliminate these repeated options over and over.

Comment: Ok, so it seems to repeat whatever the last option name is over and over again.  I'll let you know when I find the solution.

Comment: @Soiss . . . Did you see the db fiddle?  It does not repeat the last option.

Comment: I got it!  There was an issue with my terminator causing a massive loop.  Thanks for your patience and the example!!!